# GEE JavaScript Expecting FeatureCollection but receiving Feature

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, google-earth

I am working on calculating NDVI values for both SEN2 and SEN3 from the same time frame and storing the results on my Google Drive.
I have a feature collection called "region" which is an assemble of 4 fields (polygons) and is imported from my assets.

I run this code to compute and save NDVI values for each field and for both SEN2 and SEN3 but I am unable to save the outputs as the task cannot be complete due to this error:

```
Error: Collection.geometry, argument 'collection': Invalid type. Expected type: FeatureCollection. Actual type: Feature.
```

This is the code:

```
//define all AOI
var field1 = ee.FeatureCollection(region.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","00000000000000000000").first());
var field2 = ee.FeatureCollection(region.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","00000000000000000001").first());
var field3 = ee.FeatureCollection(region.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","00000000000000000002").first());
var field4 = ee.FeatureCollection(region.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","00000000000000000003").first());
var fields = [field1, field2, field3, field4];

//Get the ndvi for the specific field and time
function get_ndvi_sen2(region, startdate, enddate){
  region = ee.FeatureCollection(region)
  var ndvi_s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
    .filterDate(startdate, enddate)
    .map(function (image) {
      return image
        .clipToCollection(region)
        .normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
        .updateMask(image.select('QA60').not());
    })
    .median()
    .rename('ndvi_s2');

  var ndvi_s2_Features = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(ndvi_s2
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: 10
  })
  .get('ndvi_s2'))
  .map(function (ndvi_s2) {
    return ee.Feature(null, {ndvi_s2: ndvi_s2});
  })
  );
  return ndvi_s2_Features;
}
function get_ndvi_sen3(region, startdate, enddate){
  var SEN3 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI')
                    .filterDate(startdate, enddate);

  // Select bands for NDVI and apply band-specific scale factors.
  var SEN_corr = SEN3.select(['Oa17_radiance', 'Oa08_radiance'])
                .median()
                // Convert to radiance units.
                .divide(ee.Image([0.00493004, 0.00876539]));
  region = ee.FeatureCollection(region)
  var ndviSEN3 = SEN_corr
        .clipToCollection(region)
        .normalizedDifference(['Oa17_radiance', 'Oa08_radiance'])
        .rename('ndviSEN3');

  var ndviFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(ndviSEN3
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
      geometry: region,
      scale: 10
    })
    .get('ndviSEN3'))
    .map(function (ndviSEN3) {
      return ee.Feature(null, {ndviSEN3: ndviSEN3});
    })
  );
  return ndviFeatures;
}
function write_to_drive(col, disc, selc, folder){
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: col,
    description: disc,
    selectors: selc,
    folder: folder
  })
}

var start = '2019-03-1'
var end = '2019-04-01'
var sen2_disc, sen2_selc = 'ndvi_s2';
var sen3_disc, sen3_selc = 'ndviSEN3';
var sen2_folder = 'GOOD/SEN2'
var sen3_folder = 'GOOD/SEN3'

for (var i in fields){
  var sen2_loop = get_ndvi_sen2(fields[i], start, end);
  var sen3_loop = get_ndvi_sen3(fields[i], start, end);
  write_to_drive(sen2_loop,sen2_disc,sen2_disc,sen2_folder)
  write_to_drive(sen3_loop,sen3_disc,sen3_disc,sen3_folder)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write

```
var field1 = ee.FeatureCollection(region.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","00000000000000000000").first());
```

You haven't defined the global variable `region` in the code you shared, but assuming it is a collection of features, `first()` of it is a feature, not a feature collection.

Unfortunately, while the documentation of `ee.FeatureCollection()` says that it converts single Features to FeatureCollections, this doesn't appear to work all the time. (I've reported this as a bug.)

Try this:

```
var field1 = ee.FeatureCollection(region.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","00000000000000000000"));
```

That way you actually have a FeatureCollection, that happens to contain a single element, and you don't need to take the extra step of `.first()`.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly!